# White screen opens at app start and freezes

Tags: android

Just recently I ran my app on the emulator API 25 no problem occurs. However on my alcatel API 22 it showed a blank white screen at start, and thats it. It doesn't even stop working, just a white screen. It wasn't happening before and I didn't change anything in my main activity.
What do you think may be the issue?

Comment: Connect your phone to the computer in debug mode. Run your app and check Android Studio Monitor for errors. If you find any add them / the stack trace in your question.

Comment: I found out it was because of a character I had inserted on a button's text I just removed it and the problem was solved .In the log can I found ................................................................................................................07-11 22:25:38.936 17074-17074/com.example.zero.fragments A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:70] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0xf0

Comment: can you give more details , but at eh first sight i think that in your app gradle there minsdk version is higher than 22 check it and let me know